# Raising Argonaut tuple arity to 23

Tags: scala, argonaut

I'm trying to implement a CodecJson with arity 23. It looks something like this:

```
implicit def infoCodec: CodecJson[Info] = CodecJson(
    (x: Info) => argonaut.Json(
      "a" -> x.a,
      "b" -> x.b,
      "c" -> x.c,
      ...(a total of 23 fields)
    ),
cursor => for {
      a <- cursor.get("a")
      b <- cursor.get("b")
      c <- cursor.get("c")
      ...(a total of 23 fields)
    }
  )
```

However, I get type errors on all fields such as:

```
type mismatch;
  Id|Json
      "a" -> x.a,
```

How do I convert `x.a` into Json - and so on for all other fields/types?

Thank you!

Comment: BEWARE: [Argonaut is vulnerable under DoS attacks](https://github.com/argonaut-io/argonaut/issues/314) that exploit [hash code collision weakness of Scala's default hash maps](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11203).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Scala functions are limited to an arity of 22. So this may just be your problem.

You need to use the "methods" supplied by Argonaut for constructing a JSON: `:=` and `->:`. For example:

```
case class MyCookie(name: String, value: String)
implicit def myCookieCodec = CodecJson((c: MyCookie) =>
    ("name" := c.name) ->:
    ("value" := c.value) ->: 
    jEmptyObject,
    c => for {
        name <- (c --\ "name").as[String]
        value <- (c --\ "value").as[String]
    } yield Cookie(name, value)
)
```

The `->:` implies a "prepend", this means you have to read a chain of `->:` calls from right to left. Regarding the example above:

1. Start with an empty object (`jEmptyObject`)
2. Add a key "value" with the value "c.value" (`("value" := c.value)`)
3. Add a key "name" with the value "c.name" (`("name" := c.name)`)

`:=` constructs a JSON key-value pair.

I think your decoding part (the second parameter to `CodecJson.apply()`) should work as intended.